# Protractor and Typescript: Class defined in different file but the same module causes 'declaration exception'

Tags: module, typescript, protractor

I am completely confused what I am doing wrong here.

Say I have a test file 'SimpleTest.ts' containing the following:

```
/// <reference path="../otherdir/simpleclass.ts" />
module MyModule.SubModule {
    describe("this test", () => {
        var myObject: SimpleClass = new SimpleClass("");

        it("doesn't even get here!", () => {
            expect(myObject).toBeDefined();
        });
    });
}
```

The class here is defined in a different file, but in the same module, like this:

```
module MyModule.SubModule {
    export class SimpleClass {
        constructor(private myMember: string) {}
    }
}
```

So both definitions reside in the same module. Typescript compiles fine, everything looks OK.

But when I start protractor (yes, I have configured 'specs:' path to the files correctly), it stops with the error

```
   this test
    encountered a declaration exception - fail
```

I know that I could get it to work by using module.export and require, but this is not a good solution.

First, I loose the type checking of typescript, when I use javascript 'require', and the type checking is one of the reasons why I'm using it in the first place.

Second, I think this is bad style to mix plain javascript into typescript code.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance, 
Regards,
Jörg

Comment: TypeScript will happily output code for both commonjs and amd modules. I am using Jasmine (which is what Protractor uses) with modules just fine - and I'm doing it with AMD, which is slightly trickier as you need to make Jasmine wait until you are ready. http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201407/Blog/Combining-TypeScript-Jasmine-And-AMD-With-RequireJS/

Comment: Have you found a solution ? I have the same problem, and couldn't find any solution till now.

Answer (score 0):

Stop using internal modules.

It honestly helped me a lot when trying to understand TypeScript.
My experiences with internal TypeScript modules are answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31777388/replace-require-on-typescript-bundle)
.
You can read the article of Steve Fenton [here](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2015/05/stop-mixing-typescript-internal-and-external-modules/) for more details.

I hope this is of any help still to you.